# Error sending mail with Laravel app/Gmail in production

Tags: laravel, email, gmail

I have this error when I try to send mail with Laravel 9 app using Gmail:

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "*************@gmail.com" using the following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor h4-20020a056830034400b0060603221274sm8631029ote.68 - gsmtp".". Authenticator "PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required. Learn more at 534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor h4-20020a056830034400b0060603221274sm8631029ote.68 - gsmtp".". Authenticator "XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "334", with message "334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==".".

This is my .env configuration.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=************@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=************@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Claims - *****"
```

I've been reading, and apparently since 5/22/2022 you can no longer activate the option to allow access to less secure applications in Gmail... so, how can we solve this? is this really my problem or another?

Comment: just use another service like sendgrid, sendinblue etc. they have free plans also

Comment: You may have 2 factor auth enabled. also i wouldnt bother with gmail to send emails, its a pain.

Comment: Can you include your authorization code. Looks like somethings wrong with your authorization.

Comment: Hello. To be honest, I didn't know that I had to configure something in my app to be able to use the Gmail mailbox... I thought that changing the mail parameters in the .env was enough. What should I do then? On the other hand, my company uses emails from Gmail accounts to communicate, so how can I use sendgrid for example? allow me to use gmail accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google recently changed there security protocol about less secure apps, that's why it's showing the error.

Comment: yes, i just read about that. So, now, how can we continue using gmail?

Comment: im facing this exact issue. when i try to turn on the Less secure app access I cant see the option for turning it on